# SVN commit authentication failure

Tags: svn, authentication, commit

*Note: I have read through the last 150 svn commit error questions and none of the answers solved my problem.*

I'm trying to set up a simple svn server from which I can checkout and to which I can commit files.

conf/svnserv.conf

```
[global]
anon-access = none
auth-access = rw
password-db = passwd
#authz-db = authz
```

conf/passwd

```
[users]
myuser = password
```

svn checkout from another machine works fine:

```
svn co svn://138.25.25.42:3690 test --username myuser --password password
```

then I added a local file within my local repository copy

```
echo "content" > testfile
svn add testfile
```

but when I now try to commit I get an Authentication/Authorization (german: Autorisierung) error (all 3 the same)

```
svn ci --username myuser --password password -m "lala"
svn ci . --username myuser --password password -m "lala"
svn ci test --username myuser --password password -m "lala"
```

looking at the transmissions with wireshark it looks like my username and password is ignored (?)

```
[SERVER->CLIENT]
( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) ) ( 
[CLIENT->SERVER]
2 ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops ) 25:svn://138.25.25.42:3690 21:SVN/1.6.15 (r1038135) ( ) ) 
[SERVER->CLIENT]
( success ( ( ANONYMOUS ) 36:ab25c003-0e26-4e93-98a3-6c5d9cc9a979 ) ) ( ANONYMOUS ( 0: ) ) ( success ( ) ) ( success ( 36:ab25c003-0e26-4e93-98a3-6c5d9cc9a979 25:svn://138.25.25.42:3690 ( mergeinfo ) ) ) 
[CLIENT->SERVER]
( commit ( 4:lala ( ) false ( ( 7:svn:log 4:lala ) ) ) ) 
[SERVER->CLIENT]
( failure ( ( 170001 0: 62:/build/buildd/subversion-1.6.5dfsg/subversion/svnserve/serve.c 167 ) ) )
```

Any help getting the commits working would be greatly appreciated.

**edit:** strangely, an anonymous checkout works as well; so the configuration files seem to be ignored, I just can not see why.

Comment: Anything in the logs of svnserve?

Comment: log just says svn ERR serve.c 167 170001 Authorisation failed

Comment: Where is your svnserve.conf located?

Comment: It's in the svnroot/conf. I have restarted the server supplying the path explicitly, now I get a "no repositories" error doing a checkout.

Comment: I was now able to set up a repository that can be checked out again but not in. Back to square one.. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was: I have set up the svn server directory in my home directory, and the user under which svnserve ran did not have access to it, regardless of the 777 permissions in the directory (since it had no permissions to access the parent dir).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've got the wrong token in there for "auth-access".  It should be "write" and not "rw".  Also, you should probably specify a "realm" in there so users authenticating know for what they are authenticating.

Comment: Tried it with write instead of rw and a svnserve restart, still the same error. Also added a realm, no difference.

Comment: Any chance this is a filesystem permissions issue?  Are you running svnserve behind SSH?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that there could be a typo in your checkout line.  You have "svn co svn://138.25.25.42:3690 test ..." while it should be "svn co svn://138.25.25.42:3690/test ...".

Comment: @server: # chmod -R 777 svndir, no change. Checkout works the way I did it but not with /test. May I have set up something wrong there?

Comment: I'm at a loss.  First, I don't know why anonymous would be used when you specified the username/password to the CLI.  You might want to try blowing away ~/.subversion/auth and trying again.  Did you restart the server after changing svnserve.conf?  If not, you need to.

Comment: I did restart the server every time I changed something. Deleting ~/.subversion changes nothing. I am however able to check out anonymously (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with subversion (Authentication failed). 
My solution was I needed to cut all the spaces in config files.

Like above:
conf/svnserve.conf should be:

```
[global]
anon-access=none
auth-access=write
password-db=passwd
#authz-db = authz
```

conf/passwd should be:

```
[users]
myuser=password
```

Of course the access of the svnserve.conf and passwd must be accessabele by the svnserve process.